# How to loop until the user matches the randomNumber?

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to coding and learning JAVA. I was able to execute the below code but I am not sure how to loop this until the user matches the randomNumber. Could you please help.

My current code:

```java
package com.arwa.basicExcercisePart1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer randomNumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 5: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();

        if (number == randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Wow, The entered number matched with the Random Number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, The number you entered did not match with the Random Number, Try Again: .");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note your `randomNumber` can range from 0 to 5 and you prompt for 1 to 5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

iota's answer is correct but since Aravind is learning I'd like to suggest another more didactic answer. You can use a flag to signal that the user choose the right answer and then get out of the loop. I did this below:

```java
public class RandomCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer randomNumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        boolean found = false; // flag is false at beginning

        while (!found) { // stay in the loop till answer is correct
            System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 5: ");
            int number = scan.nextInt();

            if (number == randomNumber) {
                found = true; /// will finish the loop
                System.out.println("Wow, The entered number matched with the Random Number.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, The number you entered did not match with the Random Number, Try Again: .");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `while` loop like so:

```
int number;
while((number = scan.nextInt()) != randomNumber){
    System.out.println("Sorry, The number you entered did not match with the Random Number, Try Again: ");
}
System.out.println("Wow, The entered number matched with the Random Number.");
```

Comment: In a While statement I learnt a increment is needed something like i++ , Is not necessary all the time?

Comment: @AravindViswanathan No, you only need a boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop around the code that checks the user's input against the random number.

Comment: That is were I am confused as where to put the loop.

Comment: that would be from before int number = scan.nextInt(); to after the else statement